# Lex Yacc parser compiling get few errors tried searching solution cant find

Tags: yacc, lex

We have a task to compile a lex and a yacc praser code then run them together by using the cc tab.y.c -ll -Ly command when we do each apart they compile just fine but the compile both parts as one gives 10 lines of errors.

First part is Lex Code:

```
%option yylineno
    %pointer
    %{
        #include <stdlib.h>
        #include <string.h>
        void yyerror(const char *);
    %}
    low \_
    identifier {letters}{digit}*{low}{letters}|{letters}
    stringERR {doubleQuotes}{doubleQuotes}+|{doubleQuotes}
    charERR {singleQuotes}+{digits}*{letters}*{singleQuotes}+
    ERR {charERR}|{stringERR}
    type boolean|string|char|integer|intptr|charptr|var
    dbland "&&"
    devide "/"
    assign "="
    equal "=="
    greater ">"
    lesser "<"
    greaterequal ">="
    lesserequal "<="
    minus "-"
    plus "+"
    not "!"
    notequal "!="
    or "||"
    multiply "*"
    power "^"
    AND "&"
    literBool true|false
    letter [a-z]|[A-Z]
    letters {letter}+
    singleQuotes '
    literChar {singleQuotes}{letter}{singleQuotes}
    digit [0-9]
    digitZero 0
    octalDigit [1-7]
    octal {digitZero}{octalDigit}{digitZero}*{octalDigit}*
    digits {digit}+
    digitNoZero[1-9]
    decimal {digit}|{digitNoZero}{digits}
    hexLetter A|B|C|D|E|F
    hex 0(x|X){digit}+{hexLetter}*|0(x|X){digit}*{hexLetter}+
    letterB b
    digitOne 1
    binaryInt ({digitZero}|{digitOne})+{letterB}
    integer {binaryInt}|{hex}|{octal}|{decimal}
    doubleQuotes \"
    ltrlString {doubleQuotes}{letters}*{decimal}*{hex}*{octal}*{binaryInt}*{dbland}*{devide}*{assign}*{equal}*{greater}*{lesser}*{greaterequal}*{lesserequal}*{minus}*{plus}*{not}*{notequal}*{or}*{multiply}*{AND}*{power}*{doubleQuotes}
    comment {backslash}{parcent}{space}*({letters}*{space}*{identifier}*{space}*{decimal}*{space}*{hex}*{space}*{octal}*{space}*{binaryInt}*{space}*{dbland}*{devide}*{assign}*{equal}*{greater}*{lesser}*{greaterequal}*{lesserequal}*{minus}*{$nus}*{plus}*{not}*{notequal}*{or}*{multiply}*{AND}*{power}*{ltrlString}*)*{space}{parcent}{backslash}
    colon ":"
    openSq "["
    closeSq "]"
    semicolon ";"
    parcent "%"
    space " "
    comma ","
    backslash "/"
    clos ")"
    opn "("
    charptr charptr
    pointer {colon}{space}{charptr}|"="{space}"&"{identifier}
    pointerErr "&"{identifier}|{charptr}

    ELSE "else"{space}*
    statif "if"{space}*
    whileLoop "while"{space}*
    returnState "return"{space}*
    func "procedure"{space}*

    %%
    {dbland} return dbland;
    {devide} return devide;
    {assign} return assign;
    {equal} return equal;
    {greater} return greater;
    {lesser} return lesser;
    {greaterequal} return greaterequal;
    {lesserequal} return lesserequal;
    {minus} return minus;
    {plus} return plus;
    {not} return not;
    {notequal} return notequal;
    {or} return or;
    {multiply} return multiply;
    {power} return power;
    {AND} return AND;
    {literBool} return literBool;
    {literChar} return literChar;
    {decimal} return decimal;
    {hex} return hex;
    {octal} return octal;
    {binaryInt} return binaryInt;
    {ltrlString} return ltrlString
    {type} return type;
    {identifier} return identifier;
    {ERR} return ERR;
    {comment} return comment;
    {pointer} return pointer;
    {pointerErr} return pointerErr;
    {statif} return statif;
    {ELSE} return ELSE;
    {whileLoop} return whileLoop;
    {returnState} return returnState;
    {func} return func;
    {semicolon} return semicolon;
    {comma} return comma;
    [\*\(\)\.\+\-\%]  { return *yytext; }
    [0-9][0-9]*         { return 'n'; }
    [ \t\n]             ; /* skip whitespace */
    %%
    int yywrap(void) {
        return 1;
    }
```

yacc  code:

```
%token low identifier stringERR charERR ERR type operator literBool letter
%token dbland literChar decimal hex octal integer
%token binaryInt ltrString comment pointer pointerErr
%token statif ELSE whileLoop returnState func comma semicolon
%token EOL LPAREN RPAREN UMINUS

%left equal greater notequal lesser greaterequal lesserequal
%left '|' %left '&' %left SHIFT /* << >> */
%left minus plus
%left multiply devide '%' MOD %left power
%left not or AND comma
%nonassoc UMINUS
%%
s: BLOCK;
BLOCK: expr|logicOp|varible_declaration|ifExp|whileExp|procExp|semicolon;
expr: exp{printtree($1);}
      exp:
          identifier                   {$$=mknode(yytext,NULL,NULL);}
          | LPAREN expr RPAREN      {$$=$2;}
          | exp plus exp          {$$= mknode("+" $1,$3);}
          | exp minus exp         {$$= mknode("-" $1, $3);}
          | exp multiply exp      {$$=mknode("*" $1, $3);}
          | exp devide exp        {$$=mknode("/" $1, $3);}
          | "-" exp %prec UMINUS                   {-$2}
varible_declaration: var{printtree($1);}
                     var : "VAR" identifier_list ":" typet ";" {$$ = mknode("var", $2, $4);}
                     typet:
                           integer{$$ = mknode(yytext,NULL,NULL);}
                           |binaryInt {$$ = mknode(yytext,NULL,NULL);}
                           |type {$$ = mknode(yytext,NULL,NULL);}

identifier_list: identifier_list comma identifier_list
                 {$$= mknode(",",$1, $3);}
                 |identifier {$$ = mknode(yytext,NULL,NULL);}


logicOp: op{printtree($1);}
          op:exp equal exp {$$ = mknode("==",$1,$3);}
            |exp notequal exp {$$ = mknode("!=",$1,$3);}
            |exp or exp {$$ = mknode("||",$1,$3);}
            |exp AND exp {$$ = mknode("&&",$1,$3);}
            |exp greater exp {$$ = mknode(">",$1,$3);}
            |exp greaterequal exp {$$ = mknode(">=",$1,$3);}
            |exp lesser exp {$$ = mknode("<",$1,$3);}
            |exp lesserequal exp {$$ = mknode("<=",$1,$3);}

ifExp: if{printtree($1);}
      if:statif '(' logicOp ')' '{' BLOCK '}' ELSE '{' BLOCK '}' {$$ = mknode("if",$3,mknode("else",$6,$10));}
        |statif '(' logicOp ')' '{' BLOCK '}' {$$=mknode("if",$3,$6);}

whileExp: while{printtree($1)}
        while:whileLoop '(' logicOp ')' '{' BLOCK '}' {$$=mknode("while",$3,$6);}
procExp: proc{printtree($1)}
        proc:func identifier '(' identifier_list ')' returnState type '{' BLOCK '}' {$$ = mknode("procedure",$2,"TODO");}


%%
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int yylex(void);
void yyerror(const char *);
tyepdef struct node{
        char * token;
        struct node *left;
        struct  node *right;
};
node * mknode(char * token , node * left,node * right);
void printtree(node * tree);

#define yySType struct node *
#include "lex.yy.c"
main()
{       return yyparse();       }
nose * mknode(char * token,node * left, node * right)
{
        node * newnode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        char 8 newstr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(token)+1);
        strcpy("newstr,token");
        newnode->left=left;
        newnode->right=right;
        newnode->token=newstr;
}return newnode;
void printtree(node * tree)
{
        printf("%s\n",tree->token);
        if (tree->left) printtree(tree->left);
        if (tree->right) printtree(tree->left);
}
extern int yylineno;
void yyerror(const char *s)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s at line %d\n", s, yylineno);
    return;
}
```

the errors we get are the following:

```
[tzurisa@Ac-Aix backup]$ nano test.l
[tzurisa@Ac-Aix backup]$ lex test.l
[tzurisa@Ac-Aix backup]$ yacc test.y
[tzurisa@Ac-Aix backup]$ cc -o test y.tab.c -ll -Ly
test.y:63: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘struct’
test.y:68: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
test.y:69: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
In file included from test.y:72:
test.l: In function ‘yylex’:
test.l:74: error: ‘assign’ undeclared (first use in this function)
test.l:74: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
test.l:74: error: for each function it appears in.)
In file included from test.y:72:
test.l:94: error: ‘ltrlString’ undeclared (first use in this function)
test.l:95: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘break’
test.y: At top level:
test.y:75: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
test.y:83: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘return’
test.y:84: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
test.y: In function ‘yyparse’:
test.y:20: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘yyvsp’
test.y:21: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘yyvsp’
test.y:22: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘yyvsp’
test.y:23: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘yyvsp’
test.y:24: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token
test.y:51: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token
test.y:53: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token
```

will appriciate the help of anyone who can tell us whats wrong here we have tried many things we still get these errors ..

Answer (score 1):

If you look at line 63 of `test.y`, as indicated in the first error message, you will see the first problem; you misspelled `typedef`. Fix that, and then check remaining errors, if any, by looking at the indicated lines.